# In MVC3, is there a downside to having every action run under https?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, https

I have a site which has to be secure - is there a downside to having the [RequireHttps] attribute on the home controller?

Comment: How is this related to MVC? HTTPS makes your communication secure, but slower no matter which kind of framework you use to serve the pages.

Comment: How is this not related to MVC? How many other frameworks utilize the attribute [RequireHttps]?  How much slower will asp.net mvc3 specifically run?

Comment: Look at the answer you selected. It is the answer to the question: "What are the down sides to using HTTPS communication on all home page requests?". There are no ASP.NET MVC involved.

Comment: @Qua: I think you should probably look up the websters definition of context, because the concept is definitely not within your grasp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your *Specific* question, there are only three downsides I can think of if you require Https on your HomeController.

1. There is an insignificant increase in server CPU per request.
   (If this application is served to millions/billions of users this may not be insignificant over a specific time)
2. There is an insignificant increase in network activity per request.
   (this also applies to number of requests over a specific time)
3. If your certificate ever expires, users will get a negative experience of your Home pages.

Comment: Thank you for the itemized list Erik.  This will only be used by a handful of people so these increases will not take a large toll in overall server performance in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

#### Descriptiom

#### Off course, if your certificate expires your user get warnings.

But if you want to add the Https Attribute to your whole site there are 2 ways you can do that.

1. Redirect in the `Application_BeginRequest` method.
2. Using `Conditional Filters`. You can add the `[Https]` attibute to every Action method, to a specific Controller or any other condition

#### Samples

1. Redirect in the `Application_BeginRequest` method.

   ```
   protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if ( !Request.IsSecureConnection)
       {
            string path = string.Format("https{0}", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(4));
            Response.Redirect(path);
       }
    }
   ```
2. Using `Conditional Filters`

   - Add this class to your project

     ```
     public class ConditionalFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
     {
         private readonly
             IEnumerable<Func<ControllerContext, ActionDescriptor, object>> _conditions;

         public ConditionalFilterProvider(
             IEnumerable<Func<ControllerContext, ActionDescriptor, object>> conditions)
         {

             _conditions = conditions;
         }

         public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(
             ControllerContext controllerContext,
             ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
         {
             return from condition in _conditions
                     select condition(controllerContext, actionDescriptor) into filter
                     where filter != null
                     select new Filter(filter, FilterScope.Global, null);
         }
     }
     ```
   - Change your `global.asax` `RegisterGlobalFilters` method to add the `[Https]` attribute to every ActionMethod

     ```
     public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
     {
         IEnumerable<Func<ControllerContext, ActionDescriptor, object>> conditions =
             new Func<ControllerContext, ActionDescriptor, object>[] { 
             (c, a) => new RequireHttpsAttribute()
         };

         var provider = new ConditionalFilterProvider(conditions);
         FilterProviders.Providers.Add(provider);

         filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
     }
     ```

#### More Information

- [Phil Haack - Conditional Filters in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/25/conditional-filters.aspx)

Comment: I am not having an issue having the whole site surrounded with https, I was just curious if there was a downside to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a downside.

Some of reasons are:
pages can not be cached in a shared cache,
encryption and description has to be done, on both sides browser and server,
has to use trusted certificates on server side to avoid connection is not secure (certificates are not cheap).

BUT performance cost (it is very low performance cost) has to be paid to have secure sites, so if needed use HTTPS, and for some important data exchange, delete HTTP and enable only HTTPS binding on your web site.

Comment: Thank you @buda, the site already has a certificate and no whole page caching is being done.  My main concern is performance, so it is nice to hear running https will not be too burdensome on the server.  This will not be a high traffic site.